# Page control with current page dot as larger not working (UIPageControl with scroll)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I am using this code but it doesn't show the first dot (complete white).

Implementation overview:

in viewDidAppear -

```
adjustDots()
```

in scrollViewDidScroll -

```
let page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
adjustDots()
```

we have :

```
  func adjustDots()
        {
            pageControl.subviews.forEach {
                $0.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.15, y: 1.15)
            }
            pageControl.subviews[pageControl.currentPage].transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)



            self.pageControl.subviews[self.pageControl.currentPage].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            self.pageControl.subviews[self.pageControl.currentPage].centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.pageControl.subviews[0].centerYAnchor , constant: 0)

          self.pageControl.subviews[self.pageControl.currentPage].centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.pageControl.subviews[0].centerXAnchor , constant: 0)

        }
```

what could be wrong here possibly? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For unclear reasons you are messing with the internals of the UIPageControl (its subViews). You should not do that. The first dot is white in the beginning, to indicate that the first page is selected. If you want another dot to be white, set the '`currentPage`' property.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol for details.